# Paypal digital goods login page appears only for a few seconds then disappears

Tags: javascript, html, .net, paypal, asp-classic

I am implementing paypal digital goods on our website development using asp.net.

I have gone through the documentations but no solution yet.

I have implemented the integration codes from the paypal dg integration wizard, however, the paypal windows appears in form of a mini-browser for a few seconds and then disappears back to our website.

The codes am using are listed below:

```
<!-- this is placed at the point where the paypal button will appear -->

<form action='Checkout.java' method='post'  target="_top">
    <input type='image' name='paypal_submit' id='paypal_submit' src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_dg_pay_w_paypal.gif' border='0' align='top' alt='Pay with PayPal'/>
</form>

<!-- this script is added before the closing of html body tag -->

<script src = 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js' type='text/javascript'></script>   


<script type='text/javascript'>

   var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow(
    {
        trigger: 'paypal_submit',
        expType: 'instant'              //'mini'          //'popup'             //'instant'
    //PayPal will decide the experience type for the buyer based on his/her 'Remember me on your computer' option.
    });  

</script>
```

All the .java has been downloaded into the root of the web application.

Does anyone have a pointer for me please?